# VirtualBox : Getting Error: Cannot retrieve repository medta data repomd.xml for repository fedora 14-i386 installation

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora, iso-image

I am trying to install **Fedora-14-i386-DVD.iso** using **VirtualBox-5.0.10-104061-Win.exe** on windows 7.

But as soon as I check this option **[_] Fedora 14 - i386** as additional repositories, I got error.

> These are the links from where I have downloaded

[Fedora iso : https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/14/Fedora/i386/iso/   ] and

[Virtualbox: //download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.10/    ]
Add "https:" before this link to work.  (I don't have enough rep to paste two links)

> [This is the error message I got: Click Here To Open This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH4NT.jpg)

How can I install it correctly since If I go without this option my guest addition doesn't build correctly.

> "I want to do it all off-line means without internet using rpm, iso or other files."

Comment: Fedora 14 is years (4 years!) after EOL (end of life). Current version is 23. The repositories and packages for outdated releases are long gone. Please try to install some up-to-date version.

Comment: working with Fedora10 both (x86-64 and i386), both are working no problem with them. Just asking if someone using It. Same problem I got with Fedora16 also, I know it is also outdated

Comment: Can you help me to get complete iso for Fedora-23, Here on this website  (https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/). I am getting only live version (1.4GB) , Where I want to install it, internet is not connected there. **I have to do it(installation) offline**.  So I need complete .iso.